# IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

помогите пожалуйста не могу понять, что именно делаю не так, думаю ошибка глупая, но не хватает знаний

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import warnings 
from sklearn import cross_validation, svm
warnings.simplefilter('ignore') # отключим предупреждения Anaconda
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Vika\\Downloads\\ENB2012.csv', ';')
data.head()
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score
kfold = 5 #количество подвыборок для валидации
itog_val = {} #список для записи результатов кросс валидации разных алгоритмов 
X = data.values[::, 0:8]
y = data.values[::, 0:1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print ('обучающая выборка:\n', X_train[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('тестовая выборка:\n', X_test[:7])
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=60) 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val['AdaBoostClassifier'] = scores.mean()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
clf.score(X_test, y_test) 
clf.predict(X_test) 
print ('AdaBoostClassifier:\n', X_test[:9])
```

ошибка [image: ошибка]

Comment: Код нужно публиковать текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: ок, сейчас переделаю

Comment: попробуйте минимальный пример кода создать, к примеру: `import numpy as np; np.arange(5)[0,0]` (одномерному массиву индексы как двумерному передаются, что ошибку вызывает).

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: Если вы используете [данный data set](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Machine-Learning-in-Java/blob/master/MLJ-Chapter3/data/ENB2012_data.xlsx) то вам нужна либо линейная регрессия (т.к. классификатор ожидает целые числа в качестве целевого ветора) либо вам надо преобразовать `y_train` в целые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже [AdaBoostClassifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.fit) ожидает `1D array` в качестве `y`.

Попробуйте:

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

если `y_train` не целочисленного типа, то вам возможно придется сначала преобразовать его (чтобы избежать `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`):

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, (y_train.ravel()*1000).astype(int))
```

или воспользоваться одной из моделей линейной регрессии вместо классификатора

Comment: спасибо, но выводятся только единицы, что я снова не так делаю?                 from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=70) 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, (y_train.ravel()*1000).astype(int), cv=kfold)
itog_val['AdaBoostClassifier'] = scores.mean()
print ('итог', itog_val) ,                                                                      выдает такой ответ :                                                                             итог {'AdaBoostClassifier': 1.0}

Comment: @user280357, по-моему, вы много чего делаете не так. [Во первых вы выбрали неправильный столбец в качестве `y` - в качестве `y` - у вас должны быть последние два столбца](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/energy+efficiency). Во вторых вам нужно не классифицировать а предсказывать числовое значение - т.е. вам нужна линейная регрессия вместо классификатора...

Comment: классификатор выбран потому что мой дипломный руководитель сказал взять его, в качестве у взят последний столбец потому что он предсказывает исправность или неисправности модели

Comment: @user280357, вы выбрали в качестве `y` - первый столбец (`data.values[::, 0:1]`) или в вашем CSV файле порядок столбцов не соответствует [оригинальному data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00242/ENB2012_data.xlsx)? Мы вообще говорим об одних и тех же данных или нет? Если у вас совершенно другие данные, не имеющие отношения к [Energy efficiency Data Set ](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/energy+efficiency) то можете смело игнорировать мои комментарии

Comment: да столбец у первый, неправильно написала я .  и в нем указаны значения исправностей или неисправностей, файл соответствует всем коду.

Comment: @user280357, я так понял, что речь идет о других данных (это не "Energy efficiency Data Set")?

Comment: я ссылалась на эту задачу, у меня немного другие данные, могу прислать. у меня 21 столбец и первый столбец это у с исправностями или неисправностями, остальные столбцы набор данных.

Comment: @user280357, вы получили ответ на данный конкретный вопрос `IndexError: too many indices for array`, поэтому я бы вам посоветовал открыть новый вопрос, привести ссылку на ваши данные и часть кода, где у вас возникли проблемы. Пытаться получить ответы на все вопросы, которые у вас возникли или возникнут по ходу решения вашего дипломного проекта в рамках одного вопроса SO - противоречит правилам SO.

Comment: @user280357, кстати, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;-)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо вам